# Issue writing a PDF file from scratch

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate a simple PDF file (text only) programmatically.
With most PDF reader the file looks exactly like I want but some PDF readers won't open the file and report it as damaged.
I've removed every elements from the file leaving only the first void page to debug the code and found the problem but without any results, it's still recognized as damaged.

This is the raw PDF data:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
   /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
   /Count 1
   /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
   /Parent 2 0 R
   /Resources <<
   >>
   /MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ]
>>
endobj
xref
0 4
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000010 00000 n 
0000000067 00000 n 
0000000138 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 4
   /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
248
%%EOF
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this PDF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which readers don't like this file? Also, what does the spec say?

Comment: I've seen the spec for those few commands but I can't find anything wrong.

Comment: I've teste with several readers, the first I've found that report it as damaged and won't open it is OfficeSuite Pro. I've tested the file with Acrobat XI, and even if it opens the file correctly, if I check the file with preflight it reports the file as damaged.

Comment: *This is the raw PDF data* - unfortunately not raw enough as it does not allow to see your actual line breaks. E.g. It is not possible to see whether your xref entries correctly have a length of 20 bytes or incorrectly merely 19 bytes. Thus, please supply the pdf as binary download.

Comment: GREAT!!!! You are right!!!! I've made a mistake formatting the xref entries leaving a final space like I'm using only \n as line break, but using \r\n format line feed I have to remove the final space!!! THANKS A LOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

Per spec `/Resources` is required although it can be empty. Adding  `/Resources <<>>` to object 2 or 3 should suffice.

**EDIT**

The PDF below with the updated `/Resources` entry passes Acrobat's preflight when I run it. Do you get a preflight error message?

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
   /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
   /Count 1
   /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
   /Parent 2 0 R
   /MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ]
   /Resources <<>>
>>
endobj
xref
0 4
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000010 00000 n 
0000000067 00000 n 
0000000138 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 4
   /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
243
%%EOF
```

Comment: I've removed /Resources from object 3 on the last step truing to simplify at the max the PDF.
I've just tried to read it to object three but without success.
Anyway, thanks for the suggestion; I've corrected it and reported in the main post.

Comment: Tried to Copy&Paste your code.
Result still the same. Preflight recognize it as corrupted, as well as others PDF readers

Comment: What version of Acrobat? I'm using 10.1.10. Also, what preflight profile are you using? I'm using "Report PDF syntax issues"

Comment: The "Report PDF syntax issues" profile don't give me any error, even in the my first, complete, PDF file.

Comment: Which preflight report is showing it as damaged then?

Comment: I use the "Verify compatibility with PDF/A 1a" profile; I know that it is more verbose and reports many format version related issues, but it repots even if the document results damaged or not.
I've tried with simple PDF files founds on the net, with and without my same problem. I've tested them with preflight, it reports as damaged only those recognized as damaged from other PDF readers, like OfficeSuite, the files correctly opened by the readers are not reported as damaged by preflight.

Comment: Ok! "mkl" give me the correct info! The problem was on the length of the xref entries. I leave a final space but using the \r\n format for line breaks it bring the length of an xref entry to 21. Removing the final space solved the problem! Thanks anyway for your interest!